# I have a column of Vietnamese characters that can't be properly read by R when imported as a .csv

Tags: r

After converting initial excel file into a .csv and importing this into R, the characters that look fine in excel become garbled in R.

[image]

When I check the encoding of the column, I get a mix of ASCII, WINDOWS-1252, and MAC-CENTRALEUROPE. I'd like it to be either presented with Vietnamese characters in R, or all converted to Latin characters.

I tried using the stringi package to convert the column into one encoding like UTF-8, so that I could use the vietnameseConverter package to convert the column into Vietnamese characters or the Encoding() function to turn the column into Latin characters. However, the column remains in multiple different encodings.

Comment: When exporting to a CSV file, Excel may not always preserve the original encoding of the characters, leading to garbled text when importing into R.

 1. Save the file as a CSV with UTF-8 encoding
 2. In R, read in the CSV file using the `read.csv()` function and set the fileEncoding argument to "UTF-8".

If you still encounter issues with the encoding, you can try using the `iconv()` function in R to convert the character encoding of the column to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

When exporting to a CSV file, Excel may not always preserve the original encoding of the characters, leading to garbled text when importing into R.

1. Save the file as a CSV with UTF-8 encoding
2. In R, read in the CSV file using the `read.csv()` function and set the fileEncoding argument to "UTF-8".

If you still encounter issues with the encoding, you can try using the `iconv()` function in R to convert the character encoding of the column to UTF-8